# how to get the parent node of a child node

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm having issues with identifying the parent of one of my child nodes . code is as follows

```
if (!queryCommandState('InsertUnorderedList') 
    && !queryCommandState('InsertOrderedList')) {
    // If forced_root_blocks is set to false we don't have a block to indent so lets create a div
    if (!settings.forced_root_block 
        && !dom.getParent(selection.getNode(), dom.isBlock)) {
        formatter.apply('div');
    }

    each(selection.getSelectedBlocks(), function(element) {
        var indentStyleName;

        if (element.nodeName != "LI") {
            indentStyleName = dom.getStyle(element, 'direction', true) == 'rtl' ? 'paddingRight' : 'paddingLeft';

            if (command == 'outdent') {
                value = Math.max(0, parseInt(element.style[indentStyleName] || 0, 10) - intentValue);
                dom.setStyle(element, indentStyleName, value ? value + indentUnit : '');
            } else {
                value = (parseInt(element.style[indentStyleName] || 0, 10) + intentValue) + indentUnit;
                dom.setStyle(element, indentStyleName, value);
            }
        }
        if (element.nodeName=== "OL"){
            alert ("got");
        } else {
            alert (element.nodeName);
        }
    });
}
```

- want  to find the parent of the "element.nodeName"*

Comment: @Precastic I believe it is using jQuery, but `each` should probably be `$.each`.

Comment: @Precastic Are you sure you're not thinking of `Array.forEach`? Can you give a link? I googled and couldn't find it?

Comment: @user1091949 My apologies, you are right. I have deleted my comments.

Comment: @Precastic No worries buddy :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [element.parentNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.parentNode?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/Node.parentNode) to get the parent node of `element`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `jquery.parent()` or `jquery.closest()`

like,

```
$(element).parent('selecter');
```

or

```
$(element).closest('selecter');
```

or

```
$(element).parents('selecter');
```

Docs [parent()](http://api.jquery.com/parent) [closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest) [parents()](http://api.jquery.com/parents)